# storing user input into array, using sentinel value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, statistics, user-input

I am having trouble getting my sentinel value to work properly.  When the user presses 0 to exit, I want the program to display the names and salaries of all the employees, the average of all the salaries, and all employees that are within 5,000 range of the average.  I tried to write and end function but I was getting the same issue so I deleted in and inserted the commands in Main().  I know it is something silly that  I am not seeing or doing.

#This program takes an employee name followed by their salary as input
#Using a sentinel value, the user is able to continue to enter names and salaries until
#pressing 0 to quit.  Then it is supposed to print the average salary, the names and salaries of all
#employees and the names and salaries of those within 5,000 of the average

```
import statistics

names = []
salaries = []
e = None




def Main():
    e = None
    count = 1
    while e != 0:
        e = input(f"Enter Employee {count} Name      (press 0 to quit):  ")
        s = float(input(f"Enter Employee {count} salary (in hundreds)      (press 0 to quit):  "))
        L = [e, s]
        count = count+1
        names.append(L)
        salaries.append(L)
    print(names)
    print(statistics.mean(names))


Main()
```

Comment: `while e != 0` should use `"0"` as `input()` returns a string. However, turn it into a `while True:` and after you get `e` use `if e == "0": break` to exit right when the user inputs 0.

Comment: Building on @BRemmelzwaal's comment: You should also check `s != "0"`, since according to the prompt, entering `0` there will also quit

Comment: True! Would be kind of ugly with the duplicate code, but would adhere to the requirements. Wonder how an intern would be added to this system though... hahaha

Comment: Okay.  I understand the while True loop, but I am still not placing "if e == 0: break" in the correct spot.  I have tried to put it in several places, but continue to get " 'break' outside loop" error.  Help?

Comment: and thank you all for your help.  I am new to python as you can tell.